# Send JSON value to Server with Socket.io from jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, socket.io

I'm havingo some troubles to send a value from a JSON object to my Node.js server through Socket.io

Here is my code in jQuery for the client. The problem comes when trying to emit the event "check-Services". The server doesn't receive anything...

```
    
          var socket = io();

          socket.emit('DB-Update');
          socket.on('Update-Time', function(update_time){
           var date = $('Última modificación: '+update_time+'');
            $('#database-info').append(date);
          });
          socket.on('DB-Info', function(serviceList){

            for(var i=0; i'+serviceList[i].nombre+'
'+serviceList[i].url+'');
              }
              else{
                var newService = $(''+serviceList[i].nombre+'
'+serviceList[i].url+'');
              }

              var newButton=$('').attr({
                type: "button",
                id: serviceList[i].nombre,
                value: 'Comprobar '+serviceList[i].nombre,
                class: "service-button btn btn-primary",
              });

              $("#database-info").append(newService);
              $("#services-buttons").append(newButton);

              $("#"+serviceList[i].nombre).click(function(event){

                var obj = serviceList[i].nombre;
                socket.emit('check-Services', obj);
                event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          });
```

In the server I'm simply trying to print out in the console the data comming from the client. I also send some data from the server to the client in the same way (servicesList is received like that from the server) and there wasn't any problem...

Comment: Please format your code, nobody like to read is like this. ;)

Comment: I tried to convert it using JSON.stringify() but no better results...

Comment: Post the Server code.